# Possibilities of saving multiple images into a video format?

Tags: image, html, video, canvas

Let's say you have a video that you draw into a CANVAS element so that you can manipulate the pixels, for example change the video from color to black and white, can you then somehow save the result to a video?  At some time interval that you define, you are grabbing each frame and manipulating it, and you can save each frame, but how do you go about transforming a ton of images into an actual video format?

I really don't think there is a client based solution (is there?) so yes, I do accept server based solution and preferably in PHP, python, perl, or java (in that order).  In terms of changing the video, just using the video object as source and drawing it in CANVAS, lots of examples online already, here is one:

http://techslides.com/html5-video-into-canvas-with-filters/

Comment: Do you accept a server based solution ? If so what languages are you using ?

Comment: How are you changing the video? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

there is no easy way to do it, you need to manually encode frame by frame ( http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/09/record-html-canvas-animations-to-video/ )

Comment: Thanks for this link, it describes the process of pushing the individual frame images to the server and that is not really my problem.  My problem is the VirtualDub piece, is there any way to run VirtualDub programmatically? Perhaps something other than VirtualDub?  The bottom line is that I want to run the code and get a video file in the end.

Comment: would this help? http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2008/06/writing-quicktime-videos-in-pure-java/     I'm looking into trying this with simple js.

Comment: Yes, that is helpful but unfortunately, I am least familiar with Java.  However, it mentions ffmpeg which I could exec from php and that should work.